# Is there an in-universe reason as to why people are not surprised to have their pizza delivered by Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel, video-games, spider-man

In the [Spider-Man 2 (2004)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2_(2004_video_game)) video game, there is a good part of it dedicated to Peter Parker working as a pizza delivery guy for Mr. Aziz, just like in [the movie from 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2); apparently, it takes nearly an hour to do all the pizza delivery missions. The only difference with the movie is the fact the game expects you to actually manage to deliver those pizzas in time, despite having to cross the entire city and coming back in less than 3 minutes.

Like in the movie, to compensate for the lack of time, Peter is delivering the pizzas as Spider-Man to move faster through the city. However, unlike the movie, he doesn't change back to Peter Parker once he arrives to hand out the pizza. And the customers are not even surprised to have Spider-Man himself delivering a pizza to them, despite the fact they ordered a pizza to be delivered in extremely strange locations, such as in the middle of an apartment building on a window cleaning lift, at the very edge of the roof of the [Chrysler Building](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler_Building), or even on a [seamark buoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_mark) in the middle of the water:

[image: Spider-Man delivers a pizza to a customer who was waiting on a window cleaning lift. The lift is inconveniently located in a way that prevents any normal human-being to actually deliver the pizza: it is at least a dozen levels above ground, and it stopped between two floors, so there's no direct window access to the lift.]

[image: Spider-Man delivers a pizza to a customer who was waiting on the very edge of the roof of the Chrysler Building.]

[image: Spider-Man delivers a pizza to a customer who was waiting on a seamark buoy in the middle of water.]

Did they ever give an explanation as to why it is perfectly normal for Spider-Man himself to deliver pizzas in New York City?

Comment: I hesitated to create a tag for the game, but I wasn't sure how to name it. There's [tag:spider-man-2] for the movie

Comment: Probably they just assume it's a guy in a spidey costume, like in the film

Comment: @Valorum He's clinging to wall and swinging spider-web though x) I wish I could get that at my local costume shop

Comment: *"It's a video game. It doesn't need to make sense."* is the answer here.

Comment: Not really. [Peter never delivered pizzas in the comics](https://www.cbr.com/spider-man-pizza-delivery-guy/), so there's no source material to reference that I know of.

Comment: I'm thinking [Gameplay and Story Segregation trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GameplayAndStorySegregation).

Comment: "the customers are not even surprised to have Spider-Man himself delivering a pizza to them, despite the fact they ordered a pizza to be delivered in extremely strange locations, such as in the middle of an apartment building on a window cleaning lift" — I'd be more surprised if a regular pizza delivery operative managed to get to those locations. When you really think about it, delivery via Spider-Man is the only method that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not. One might speculate, but there is no in-universe justification for why nobody seems surprised that Spider-Man is delivering pizzas, nor for why they decide to order pizza in places that only Spider-Man could reach easily. There is also never an explanation for how bystanders continue to tell Spider-Man to "get a job" when he makes no attempt to hide the fact that he works part time delivering pizzas.